# Customizing QDateEdit style

Tags: c++, qt

How can i get the appearance of QDateEdit as shown on the image?

[image]

I tried changing the stylesheet, but I dont know how to achieve the spacing between the button and the edit, nor how can I change the down arrow button.

Comment: Could you post the stylesheet you have so far?

Comment: Im not sure on how to style the QDateEdit itself - my guess is that since the widget internally uses a button and a text control or something you could try to use the QPushButton specifier to override the style for the button and QLineEdit to override styles for the text input but this is just an assumption.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Well, I've deleted the comment because my answer on your `why` question needs a lot of explanations and will not fit here. It would be more like a blog post instead of comment answer and it will be kinda offtopic. Sorry for that. Also, you may try to find some articles about why not to use qt style sheets. In this case, I'd recommend to delete your comments two because I deleted my own.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: I hope we are talking about the same thing. In Qt3 there was Qt's own style-sheet system. One had to implement the styles in C++. With Qt4 they introduced a new approach similar to CSS but kept the old classes too. Maybe you mean the old one? Another issue is, changing stylesheets in QtCreator for each element individually may result in mess. I'd recommend to create a application-wide style-sheet file (qss) and apply it at application start. I even use company-wide styles, so all apps of customer look similar.

Comment: "I dont know how to achieve the spacing between the button and the edit" - there is no spacing. Button is placed top right **in** the parent and has the same border style as the parent. So it looks like they are apart, but actually the button is still inside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It comes close to the image you've posted:

```
QDateEdit
{
    background-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: rgb(100,100,100);
    spacing: 5px; 
}


QDateEdit::drop-down {
    image: url(:/new/myapp/cbarrowdn.png);
    width:50px;
    height:15px;
    subcontrol-position: right top;
    subcontrol-origin:margin;
    background-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: rgb(100,100,100);
   spacing: 5px; 
}
```

[image]

Maybe the key-word here is "sub-control". The arrows of the DateEdit or Combo-Box or anything else, don't apply all the style definitions defined in parent-control. You have to find out, how to address these sub-controls for each Qt-Class and customize the styles for each.

I hope these links will be helpful:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-customizing.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html

Comment: Only one arrow is present if you use calendarPopup option. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Its QDateEdit::drop-down.

Comment: Yes, i figured that out and managed to achieve the appearance above. If you fix your answer i will accept it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok, great, I've removed old answer and left only the useful part.

Comment: How to achieve this in QT designer studio or using python?